# How to display dwf/dwg in a web page?

Tags: html, embed

**How do you embed Autodesk 2010 dwf/dwg files in a web page?**

I found some old code that worked with the Volo View Express 2 activex control in IE, but it won't display newer drawings.

```
<iframe height="500px" width="100%" scrolling="auto" src="drawing.dwg"></iframe>
```

Is there a new/better activex control available?

Comment: Use [autodwg](http://autodwg.com) to convert dwg to pdf or jpg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Volo View 3](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?id=3239384&siteID=123112) fixed it