# embed DWG files in web site

Tags: java, web, dwg

I have been searching for this.

looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646058/how-to-display-dwf-dwg-in-a-web-page), but looks like volo3 is discontinued, so I downloaded the DWG trueView.

then in a jsp file I have:

`<EMBED SRC="randomDwg.dwg" WIDTH=800 HEIGHT=500>`

in both firefox and IE keedp showing plugin required

how can I embed a dwg file in a web page just like PDF files? (doesn't matter if a plugin is required)

Answer (score 0):

Since just about everyone has PDF why not convert the dwg to pdf.  Since pdf is vector you shouldn't lose any resolution and should still be able to zoom in.  http://anydwg.com/dwg2pdf/ might do it for you.

Comment: using .dwg is a requirement. there are a lot of movements with dwg files so I will need a dwg to pdf API/Library (in java) instead of a software for convertion